LTSpice simulation of Zener Diode Breakdown
I am trying to create a small circuit to read a voltage range of 0-12V using STM32F103 ADC. I have a simple voltage divider circuit as attached. I do have a 3.3V Zener to clamp the voltage at ADC to 3.3V (to protect the ADC pin).
Now when I simulate the circuit on LTSpice, the voltage at ADC is clipped somewhere at 3.7V
Can someone please tell me which characteristic(s) of the zener is doing this? Or is this due to an effect from another part of the circuit?

UPDATE
The original simulation screenshot got cutoff (the voltage and wattage were not showing).. Here is the complete screenshot..

Here is the zener datasheet


Low voltage Zeners have a very gradual onset of conduction. They will leak below 3.3 V and adulterate your reading and will not hard limit above 3.3 V, so might not offer sufficient protection. Better look into either/several of: Schottky rail clamps, dedicated 3.3V TVS, a pure series fault limiter, a shunt regulator based OVP

Even given that low-voltage zeners are rubbish, 3.7V seems really high at 1mA. I think the model must be too naive (a single BV parameter), and you should use a proper spice model for a BZX84C3V3 or 1N4728A, for instance.

Add a small Schottky diode from the ADC input to the 3.3V supply with an input series resistor.  That avoids the poor regulation and large voltage tolerance of the Zener and should limit the input to slightly above 3.3V.

To model a zener, using the bv property only is not enough.
You also need to define the reverse breakdown characteristics: Nbv, Ibv, Nbvl, and Ibvl.

Ibv and Ibvl are the breakdown knee currents (l = low-level)
Nbv and Nbvl are the reverse breakdown emission coefficients (l = low-level)

The reason you are getting a Zener breakdown at 3.7V is the default and unrealistic values of the parameters above.
It's unclear what exact 3V3 Zener you are trying to model so I can't tell what numbers they must have but you need to put realistic numbers into them in order to get the correct behaviour. For example, the default value of Ibvl is zero which is unrealistic, you can start with Ibvl = 1m for example.

I didn't find Nbv in my datasheet. But I see that the test current is 5mA and the dynamic resistance is 130ohms. I have updated that in the spice command and it seems like the output is stabilized at 3.4V (which is acceptable). Another question, do I need to take care of the reverse current in this case?

@RakeshMehta Nbv is not a parameter you can find in the datasheets but in the models (if there are any) that the manufacturers publish. Modifying it changes the "softness" of the breakdown/knee curve i.e. the lower it is the sharper the breakdown. For the reverse current, you can check Zener Current vs Zener Voltage curves in the datasheets and do an approximation for Ibv and Ibvl values.

Simulators can model the current-voltage curve of a Zener diode. Using the Circuit Lab simulator built it into this site simulated a 1N4728A Zener which has a nominal Zener voltage of 3.3 V:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The current though the Zener was simulated with:

Current of 276 mA, which is the max regulator current specified in the datasheet. This has the highest voltage across the Zener.
Current of 76 mA, which is the test current specified in the datasheet. This has the voltage across the Zener which is closest to the nominal Zener voltage.
Current of 494.2 uA using the resistor divider from the question. This has the lowest voltage across the Zener.

The above doesn't match the LTSpice Zener clamp voltage from the question, but it does show a simulator can model the current-voltage curve for a Zener.
For Circuit Lab the following parameters are available for a Zener, where I_z matches the test current from the datasheet:

I don't use LTSpice, but hopefully this helps for what to investigate.
